# What is wrong in this sentence grammatically?

Tags: grammar

I am so sorry for asking such question. But my boss keep saying there are grammatical error in these sentences, and I for one, even after reading them over and over can't find one.

> However, these research works lack common methodology and definition
>   of 'X' to measure its efficiency, has been diverse and subjective at
>   best.
>
> Parallelly, 'Y' framework, primarily developed in climatology field to
>   study 'A' and 'B', has been gaining traction, both in classification
>   methodology advancements and its applications. The framework defines
>   10 classes based on urban and natural features with existing research
>   showing that each class to have its unique albedo profile.

I have retracted few field specific terms.

Comment: Proofreading questions are off-topic unless a specific source of concern in the text is clearly identified.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to EL&U, Martan. You need to tell us where you - or your boss - thinks there might be some error. Otherwise your question will probably be closed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

However, the research **literature** lack common methodology and definition of 'X' to measure efficiency, have been diverse and subjective.

Notes: Replaced works with literature as I use it in papers. Plural research works/literature means following word choice must cater to plural, not singular terms.

**Similarly**, 'Y' framework primarily developed in **the** climatology field to study 'A' and 'B' has been gaining traction, both in classification methodology advancements and its applications. The framework defines 10 classes based on urban and natural features with existing research showing that each class **has a** unique albedo profile.

Notes: small grammatical issues and word choice.

Let me know if any meaning has been lost as I may have misinterpreted your text. Edit: I am new here as well, so just give me any feedback you like to help out.

Comment: thank you. I think these changes makes sense.